# Where is the domain mapped to app routers?

Tags: node.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/specialRoute', function (req, res, next) {
     // route is now http://domain:3000/route/specialRoute
});

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    // route is now http://domain:3000
});

module.exports = router;
```

However, where is the 'domain' mapped to '/' ? In other words, where is the logic to route 'http://domain:3000' ->   router.get('/',

Comment: I should be on your web server. You can use nginx or apache tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

An `express.Router` is not an `express` application (which is what is used for said binding).

Usually the mapping defaults to `localhost` because you assign a domain name to an IP and the DNS does the wiring.

If you look at [Express's `listen` documentation on devdocs](https://devdocs.io/express/index#app.listen) you'd see that you can pass a host as a second parameter : `app.listen(80, "mywebsite");`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map a router to the root ("the domain") you first need an express application:

```
const app = express();
```

Then, `use` the router:

```
app.use(router);
```

To make it even neater: Express apps themselves are instances of Router so if you replace `router.get` with `app.get` it will be functionally the same.

The reason you would want to create a new Router and export it would be to have multiple router modules and then `require` them from a main file like this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use("/shop", require("./path-to-your-shop-router.js"));
```

Also, don't forget to make the server listen so you can visit it on your computer:

```
// Ports <1024 are usually restricted
app.listen(3000);
```